# Disposing of managed objects

Tags: vb.net

Please have a look at the code below:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim objCommand As SqlCommand
        Dim objCon As SqlConnection
        Dim p1 As Person
        Try
            p1 = New Person
            p1.DoSomething()
            objCommand = New SqlCommand
            Using objCommand
                Dim strConString As String = "Data Source=IANSCOMPUTER;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True"
                objCon = New SqlConnection
                Using objCon
                    objCon.ConnectionString = strConString
                    objCon.Open()
                    objCommand.Connection = objCon
                    objCommand.CommandText = "select startdate from person "
                    Dim objDR As SqlDataReader = objCommand.ExecuteReader
                    If objDR.HasRows Then
                        objDR.Read()
                        Using objCon
                            Dim startdate As String = objDR("startdate")
                        End Using
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception

            Throw
        Finally
            If objCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                objCon.Close()
            End If
            objCon = Nothing
            objCommand = Nothing
            p1=Nothing 'This line is still needed
        End Try
    End Sub
```

I understand that the code in the finally clause is pointless because the connection and command are wrapped in Using statements.

However what happens if you have your own custom classes like Person, which doesn't use unmanaged resources? Surely the FINALLY clause would be needed in this instance to ensure that the reference to the object (on the heap) is set to nothing regardless of whether an exception is thrown or not?

Answer (score 1):

When objects are referenced from a method, there is no need to set the variables to Nothing, since the objects will be "unrooted" and available for garbage collection as soon as the method call ends. When the method call ends all the local variables on the stack will be gone and the object they refer to will have no rooted references to them, making them available for garbage collection. In general you don't need to "null out" (by setting them to `Nothing` in vb.net) variables in .NET, since it does not rely on reference counting for managing objects on the heap.

Have a look at [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx) for an overview of how allocation and deallocation of memory works in .NET.

Comment: Thanks.  +1.  What happens if you have an instance variable that is an object.  Is this destroyed when the class that creates it is destroyed?

Comment: Instances of Reference type (class) aren't "destroyed" immediately. They are made available for garbage collection as soon as there are no "rooted" references to them. So in the case with an instance variable, the object it is referencing will be available for GC as soon as there are no references to the object holding the instance variable and there are no other variables referencing the object the  instance variable is referencing.